# Error "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status" while compiling

Tags: c++, g++

When I am building following source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Heap
{
    public:
        Heap()
        {
            printf("Heap()");
        }
        void* print()
        {
            printf("This is Heap Print");
        }
};

class DvHeap : public Heap
{
    public:
        DvHeap():Heap()
        {
            printf("DvHeap()\n");
        };
};

template<class T>
class base
{
    public:
        void* operator new(size_t size)
        {
            printf("base()\n");
            return T::printit().print();
        }
};

template<class T>
class derived : public base<derived<T> >
{
    static  DvHeap xx;
    public:
        static Heap& printit()
        {
            printf("DvHeap()\n");
           return xx;
        }
}; 

int main()
{
    //DvHeap *pH = new DvHeap(1);
    derived<DvHeap> *pD = new derived<DvHeap>;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error:

**[debdghos]$** g++ Ctest.cpp -o test

/tmp/ccM7XI3u.o: In function `derived<DvHeap>::printit()':
Ctest.cpp:(.text._ZN7derivedI6DvHeapE7printitEv[derived<DvHeap>::printit()]+0xf): undefined reference to`derived::xx'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can any one tell me why this happening? The code is for learning purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize static member outside of the class.

```
template<typename T>
DvHeap derived<T>::xx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete code:

```
include <stdio.h>

class Heap
{
    public:
        Heap()
        {
            printf("Heap()");
        }
        void* print()
        {
            printf("This is Heap Print");
        }
};

class DvHeap : public Heap
{
    public:
        DvHeap():Heap()
        {
            printf("DvHeap()\n");
        };
};

template<class T>
class base
{
    public:
        void* operator new(size_t size)
        {
            printf("base()\n");
            return T::printit().print();
        }
};

template<class T>
class derived : public base<derived<T> >
{
    static  DvHeap xx;
    public:
        static Heap& printit()
        {
            printf("DvHeap()\n");
           return xx;
        }
}; 
    template<typename T>
    DvHeap derived<T>::xx;
int main()
{
    //DvHeap *pH = new DvHeap(1);
    derived<DvHeap> *pD = new derived<DvHeap>;
    return 0;
}
```

Read this where you was wrong:
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/